# LevensteinDistance - Commons Lang 3.0 API

Tags: java, api, levenshtein-distance

With Commons Lang api I can calculate the similarity between two strings through the [LevensteinDistance](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). The result is the number of changes needed to change one string into another. I wish the result was within the range from 0 to 1, where it would be easier to identify the similarity between the strings. The result would be closer to 0 great similarity. Is it possible?

Below the example I'm using:

```
public class TesteLevenstein {

    public static void main(String[] args) {      

        int distance1 = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance("Boat", "Coat");
        int distance2 = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance("Remember", "Alamo");
        int distance3 = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance("Steve", "Stereo");

        System.out.println("distance(Boat, Coat): " + distance1);
        System.out.println("distance(Remember, Alamo): " + distance2);
        System.out.println("distance(Steve, Stereo): " + distance3);        

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just divide by some number. The question is what number? Probably the maximum possible distance for the given pair of strings. I think that's the length of the longer string (ie all the characters are different, plus a few more were added, compared with the shorter string).

Comment: "_Probably the maximum possible distance for the given pair of strings._" is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I did as told MRAB and took the percentage.