# compute similarity between strings based on primary similarity

Tags: java, string

I have two string like this:

```
String1: EnableAdvertResult 
String2:AdvertisementDel
```

Then I have splited them like this:

```
 X[0]=Enable X[1]=Advert X[2]=Result

 Y[0]=Advertisement Y[1]=Del
```

And then compute similarity between each pair elements, like this:

```
sim(x[0],y[0])=a, 
sim(x[0],y[1])=b, 
sim(x[1],y[0])=c, 
sim(x[1],y[1])=d, 
sim(x[2],y[0])=e, 
sim(x[2],y[1])=f
```

Now I want to know that, what is the best way to compute similarity between string1 and string2 based on above sim?

Comment: Your question is more related to algorithms. A related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings

Answer (score 0):

it is called Levenshtein distance . a C# code can be found at Levenshtein distance c# . I'm sure you can find java code too.

Answer (score 0):

You want the Levenshtein distance between strings, which is implemented in [Apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29). I've used the Apache version of Levenshtein with good results. Also see this [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629712/levensteindistance-commons-lang-3-0-api) about string comparisons.